# Android studio Bluetooth service - what is the correct way to start a thread?

Tags: multithreading, android-studio, bluetooth

I am working on a Bluetooth project in Android studio and I am stuck on calling a new thread from the main activity. I have started with the [Bluetooth example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth) and created a file `ConnectThread.java` - the code from the examples "Connect as client" tab;  And `MyBluetoothService.java` - the code from examples "Manage a connection" tab.

I can successfully start the `ConnectThread` by calling `new ConnectThread(device);` from my MainActivity and passing it the BluetoothDevice.

Now after `mmSocket.connect();` is successful in the `ConnectThread` i need to start the `ConnectedThread(mmSocket);` from the `MyBluetoothService` class. I am trying to start the thread with the following line:

`new MyBluetoothService.ConnectedThread(mmSocket);`

But I am getting the error message:

> 'com.example.project_name.MyBluettothService' is not an enclosing
> class

This is the hierarchy of the MyBluetoothService.java file (the same as in the example):

```
public class MyBluetoothService {
    public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
```

What would be the correct way to start the `ConnectedThread(mmSocket)`
?